# Is $y= \mathbb Q \cap [2 , 10] $ Regular space in $R_k$ topolgy?

Tags: general-topology

**Is $y= \mathbb Q \cap [2 , 10] $  Regular space in $R_k$ topolgy ?**

**My attempt :**

A topological space $X$ is a regular space if, given any closed set $F$ and any point $x$ that does not belong to $F$, there exists a neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ and a neighbourhood $V$ of $F$ that are disjoint. Concisely put, it must be possible to separate $x$ and $F$ with disjoint neighborhoods.

As the space  $y = \mathbb Q \cap [2 , 10]$ is not containing $[0 , 1]$ , $(y , R_k)$ is same as $(y , T)$ . Here $T$ is the standard topology.

Now let's $x$ is a point in $y$ and $x$ is not contained in the closed subset $F$ of $y$. As $F$ is a closed space and $y$ is a compact subspace of $(R , T)$ , $F$ is also a compact space. So we will be able to find a finite cover of $F$.

Now $x$ is in the open set $y - F$ . So there will be a neighbourhood $N (x , \delta)$ which is disjoint with the above finite cover .

So $y$ is a Regular  Space.

Can anyone tell me if I went wrong anywhere?

Comment: The subspace $y$ is not compact in $\mathbb{R}$ : it is not closed. Secondly you say "a finite cover of $F$", but this just says $F$ is cover by a finite number of opens; you don't know if $x$ is in the opens

Comment: Can you give me the hints to do this ? @AlexL

Comment: You have the main ideas I think. Look rather at $\bar{F}$, the closure of $F$ in $\mathbb{R}$, this will be compact and see that $x$ is not in $\bar{F}$. Then you can separate $x$ with any point of $F$ and than use the compactness of $\bar{F}$ to separate $x$ and $F$ following your ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Y = \Bbb Q \cap [2,10]$ as a subspace of $\Bbb R_K$ has the same topology as it would have had under $\Bbb R$ (usual topology). SO it's just a metric space and hence normal and regular etc.